# How do I properly Unit Test Spring Boot Reactive app with Kotlin & Kotest

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-webclient, kotest

I'm fairly new to Kotlin and Kotest, been scratching my head on how to properly unit test webflux application. Looking over kotest samples [here](https://github.com/kotest/kotest/blob/master/kotest-examples/kotest-examples-spring-webflux/src/test/kotlin/io/kotest/example/spring/GreetingControllerTest.kt), to me that looks like it's spinning up a `WebTestClient` server and is more like integration test(please correct me if I'm wrong).

My app is fairly simple, I have a rest controller that I'm using constructor injecting to inject my service.

This service uses `WebClient` to call a different external service that returns a `Mono<MyResponse>`. And my test looks something like so:

```kotlin
@SpringBootTest
class MyControllerTest : FunSpec({
  lateinit var service: MyService
  lateinit var controller: MyController

  beforeTest {
    service = mockk()
    controller = MyController(service)
  }

  test("should return my response") {
     val myResponse = MyResponse(name = "John Doe")

     every { service.getName(any()) } returns Mono.just(myResponse)

     val response = controller.getName()
     
     verify { service.getName(any()) }
    
     response shouldBe myResponse
   }
})
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
expected: MyResponse(name = "John Doe")
actual: Monojust
```

Comment: You can call `block()` on the mono to get the value. Or there are other ways https://www.baeldung.com/java-string-from-mono

Comment: @DCTID Thanks a bunch! Doing `response.block() shouldBe accounts` worked. Did some reading up on it. And I believe I'm going to go with `io.reactor.test` approach using `StepVerifier`.

Comment: I would recommend using the Kotlin extensions for the StepVerifier - then you will have a very fluent and nice way of testing the reactive methods.